# SQL return SUM as INT in PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, sum

I have a SQL query that returns SUM, and I need to use that SUM later on to sum it to another field in PHP, so I could return the TotalSum (old points + new points) to the database, but I get the following error:

> Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int

It doesn't add these values that I fetch from database.

My code is:

```
$Sum1= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(`Points`) FROM `table` WHERE `Id`=$ID ");
$Sum2= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(`PointsTwo`) FROM `table` WHERE `Id`=$ID");

$TotalSum=$Sum1+ $Sum2+ $NewPoints+ $NewPointsTwo;
```

I would like to point out that values in the columns are integers

Comment: `mysqli_query` doesn't return the values in the columns.  You need to learn how to use the "mysqli_" functions.  There are numerous examples and tutorials on the web.

Comment: You need to fecth the data and get values before using in an arithmetic operation.

Comment: add results not the resources .. mysql_query returns the resource not the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first **fetch** the result of your query like so:

```
$Sum1= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(`Points`) FROM `table` WHERE `Id`=$ID ");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($Sum1);

// $row now contains all the column values for the query
$TotalSum = $row[0] + ...
```

[Check out this tutorial](http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/mysqli-procedural-functions/) for more info on using the `mysqli` functions.